# NetSuite Merge Customers - What Does This Error Mean?

Tags: merge, netsuite

I'm trying to merge two customers and getting the error:

```
The merge of the entity <merging customer name> was blocked for the following reasons: The selected customers have different pricing levels for the same item. Change the price levels to match.
```

Where do I find these pricing levels? I've no idea where to even look.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error mentions items, I suspect that the two customers have item-level pricing and there's a mismatch between the two. On the Standard Customer Form (on your custom form it may be somewhere else),  go to the *Financial* -> *Item Pricing* sublist and cross check the item pricing for each customer. One of them has an item where the *Pricing Level* column is different between the two customers.